# plugin directory for zim wiki 0.63 on windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, zim

I would like to install some additional plugins (e.g., Mendeley) to zim. The instructions seem straightforward (from the [Mendeley-plugin readme](https://github.com/grahamrow/zim-mendeley-plugin/blob/master/README.md)):

> The plugin may be installed (like all [Zim plugins](https://github.com/jaap-karssenberg/zim-wiki/wiki/Plugins)) by cloning it to one of Zim's plugin search directories, like ~/.local/share/zim/plugins on Linux.

I therefore just have to find Zim's plugin search directory and then
`git clone https://github.com/grahamrow/zim-mendeley-plugin.git`

However, so far I was unable to find this search directory on Windows 10. *I was hoping that someone might be able to direct me to the right directory? Or, even better, maybe there is a way to check where this folder is located?*

---

My attempts so far:

- I created a `share\zim\plugins` folder here: `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\share\zim\plugins`. Cloning the mendeley plugin into this folder had no effect on zim.
- I created a `plugins` folder here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zim Desktop Wiki\share\zim\plugins`. Cloning the mendeley plugin into this folder again had no effect on zim.
- I also cloned the mendeley plugin into this folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zim Desktop Wiki\share\zim\manual\Plugins`, but this folder seems to be for manuals and not for the actual plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://zim-wiki.org/manual/Help/Config_Files.html) for more info. You should start with `%APPDATA%/zim/data` so the full path becomes `%APPDATA%/zim/data/zim/plugins/` (yes, that's 2x `zim` in the path).

Comment: Thanks! Afterwards I simply had to go to edit > preferences > plugins and tick mendeley

Comment: for me it is $HOME/.var/app/org.zim_wiki.Zim/data/zim/plugins